# How to dynamically give HTML elements an unique ID in a for..of loop(TypeScript)?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I have an array where I need to push identical HTML elements into. I have a **for..of TypeScript loop** which will dynamically add these elements into the array. I want to distinguish each element with an unique ID. Is that possible in a **for..of Typescript loop**?

Following is the code I have:

```
for (let row of this.props.users) {
    userRows.push(
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio"
                        id="customRadio1" 
                        name="customRadio" />
                </td>
            </tr>
    );
}
```

Now the `ID` is `customRadio1` and will be that for each element. I want the next HTML element to have `customRadio2` and next `customRadio3` and so on.

NB! I know this is possible to achieve with declaring a counter variable over the for..of loop and increment that for each run, so that variable can be used with the text customerRadio, like `customerRadio + {counter}`. I want to know if this is possible with only using the `row` variable in for..of loop and how?

Comment: users structure? use `map` ?

Comment: @xadm I have rewritten it to use `map` instead and it seems like a good solution. Please see the answer I have provided to my own question if you think this is a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True `map` solution should look like this:

```
const userRows = this.props.users.map( (value, index) => (
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id={'customRadio' + {index}} name="customRadio" />
    </td>
  </tr>)
);
```

Comment: But defining value as type `User` help the editor know about the attributes of the object, so you get suggestions from editor(like I am using VS 2019) about which attributes to use of the object, like e.g: email, firstname, lastname etc which will make you avoid spelling mistakes.

Comment: I still agree that array `push` can be avoided when using the variable `userRows`!

Comment: sure, it was for idea, not ideal, typed solution ;)

Comment: for brevity, there should be `<tr key={index}>` to avoid errors on updates

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
for (let i in this.props.users) {
    /* Since i is a string, we need to convert it to a number before calculating 
       1-based index (to start with 'customRadio1') */
    let index = Number(i) + 1; 
    userRows.push(
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio"
                    id={'customRadio' + index}
                    name="customRadio" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the comment from xadm about maybe using map instead, I decided to rewrite the for..of loop to a map instead, and this seems convenient and works:

```
   this.props.users.forEach((value: User, index: number) => {
        userRows.push(
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id={'customRadio' + {index}} name="customRadio" />
                </td>
            </tr>);
    });
```

If this is possible to solve with for..of loop, please let me anyway know for future knowledge.

Comment: If you look for a way to achieve this with for...loop, please see my answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144952/2140633

Comment: @UdithGunaratna It's a good alternative, but this is done with for..in and I was looking for for..of approach, if that is even possible. Both for..in and map can be used, but I like `map` as index decleration can be done on same line as `forEach` and it is not need for a separate index variable decleration on a new line. 

I still voted up your answer as it solves the problem :)